# Fastest way to escape charArray before SQL insertion

Tags: java, arrays, char, escaping

I have a char[] originalCharArray of some size.

I want to create a new char[] returnCharArray such that every time the char ' appears in the original char[], another one will be added so:

```
"Hello' World" ---> "Hello'' World"
```

What is the fastest way of doing so?
I thought about defining returnCharArray to be x2 the size of originalCharArray, and copy the chars one by one from original charArray (adding extra ' when needed) then removing the excess allocated space in the end (does that extra space matter?)

Also I thought about StringBuilding, but then I have to convert to String then to CharArray.

What is the best practice for it?

Comment: You could use PreparedStatements to do this automatically.  If you're trying to prevent SQL injection, there's more than just apostrophes to counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to replace `'` with `''` :

```
char[] c = new char[]{'H','e','l','l','o','\'',' ','W','o','r','l','d'};
String s = String.valueOf(c);
System.out.println("Before : " + s );

s = s.replaceAll("'", "''");
System.out.println("After : " + s );

char[] c_modified = s.toCharArray();

System.out.println( Arrays.toString(c_modified) );
```

Output:

```
Before : Hello' World 
After : Hello'' World
[H, e, l, l, o, ', ', , W, o, r, l, d]
```

Answer (score 2):

The method you described of going through a String to do this is probably the simplest and least painful.  Just create a new String and then do a blanket replacement of single quote to two single quotes.

```
String str = new String(originalCharArray);
str = str.replaceAll("'", "''");
char[] newCharArray = str.toCharArray();
```

## Demo